# Spfx adding of app to a sharepoint site -- issue

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx

"**Another version of this application with the same version number is already installed. You must delete the application as well as the site Recycle Bin to install this version."**

we have verified in the subsites , recycle bin and admin recycle bin but could not find the app to delete and reinstall.

could anyone help in resolving this issue how we can add the app to the site?

Comment: Go to Site contents, could you see the installed app there?

Comment: no app is not present there @Allen_MSFT